# Typescript magic: http client get does not fire the request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, httpclient, angular6

I need help :) I'm on the start of creating authorization service, and suddenly http client does not work in this service and I can't figured why and have no ideas after four hours playing with code. Service is really simple.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UrlsService, Urls } from '@app/shared/urls';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationService {
    private _permissions: string[];

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private urlsService: UrlsService) {

    }

    refreshPermissions(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get('http://localhost:54531/api/account/permissions', { observe: 'response'})
            .map(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return this._permissions;
            });
    }

    get permissions(): string[] {
        return this._permissions;
    }
```

The refreshPermissions method calls on every user's credentials update. Look at app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {  
       this.authenticationService.setCredentialsSubject.subscribe(() => this.authorizationService.refreshPermissions());
       this.authenticationService.loadCredentialsFromLocalStorage();
}
```

I have set the breakpoint on the map function to see the response structure. But instead I see the error. Moreover in network tab I can see that request hasn't fired. And finally breakpoints inside map labmda never triggerd.

[image]
[image]

I've spent four hours trying to figured out the bug, but without success. Have you any ideas what happens?

PS. The error from the first screen

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at AuthorizationService.refreshPermissions (webpack-internal:///./src/app/core/authentication/authorization/authorization.service.ts:14:14)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (webpack-internal:///./src/app/app.component.ts:40:116)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:245:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:192:22)
    at Subscriber._next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:133:26)
    at Subscriber.next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:97:18)
    at Subject.next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js:66:25)
    at AuthenticationService.setCredentials (webpack-internal:///./src/app/core/authentication/authentication.service.ts:86:37)
    at AuthenticationService.loadCredentialsFromLocalStorage (webpack-internal:///./src/app/core/authentication/authentication.service.ts:61:14)
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (webpack-internal:///./src/app/app.component.ts:41:36)"
```

Comment: I don't know what your `httpClient` is but it is strange to see that `get()` is immediately followed by `map()`. Shouldn't there be `await`, promise or something?

Comment: you need to subscribe refreshPermissions, too:
this.authenticationService.setCredentialsSubject.subscribe(() => this.authorizationService.refreshPermissions().subscribe(result => {}));

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I've added imports section in code sample, `httpClient` from `@angular/common/http`. `httpClient.get` returns and observable.

Comment: @A.Winnen Thank you, now I understand that if there are no subscribers - observable won't fires.

Comment: @A.Winnen You can post the answer or I'll do it later.

Comment: i posted it as an answer with some additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't subscripe to refreshPermissions function. Without subscribe, your function won't be fired.

you could simple fix this by using this ngOnInit function:

```
ngOnInit() {  
   this.authenticationService.setCredentialsSubject.subscribe(() => this.authorizationService.refreshPermissions().subscribe(result => {}));
   this.authenticationService.loadCredentialsFromLocalStorage();
}
```

even better than having multiple subscribes is to use one of rxjs's operators like flatmap:

```
ngOnInit() {  
    this.authenticationService.setCredentialsSubject.flatMap(() => 
        this.authorizationService.refreshPermissions()
    ).subscribe(result => {
        //do something with result of refreshPermissions observable
    });
    this.authenticationService.loadCredentialsFromLocalStorage();
}
```

**Final code**

permissions.service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UrlsService, Urls } from '@app/shared/urls';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

type PermissionType = 'Permission1' | 'Permission2';
type PermissionsSubject = BehaviorSubject<PermissionType[]>;

export class AuthorizationService {
    private _permissionsSubject: PermissionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<PermissionType[]>([]);

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private urlsService: UrlsService) {

    }

    refreshPermissions(): void {
        const getPermissionsObservable = this.httpClient
            .get<PermissionType[]>(this.urlsService.getUrl(Urls.GET_PERMISSIONS));
        getPermissionsObservable.subscribe(permissions => this._permissionsSubject.next(permissions));
    }

    get permissions(): PermissionType[] {
        return this._permissionsSubject.value;
    }

    get permissionsSubject(): PermissionsSubject {
        return this._permissionsSubject;
    }
}
```

in app.component

```
ngOnInit() {
    authenticationService.setCredentialsSubject.subscribe(() => authorizationService.refreshPermissions());
    authenticationService.loadCredentialsFromLocalStorage()
}
```

Comment: Because it is predictable and easy to use. F.e. edit service should refresh permissions on user action and than do smth with permissions. One line of code: `this.permissionsService.refreshPermissions().then(permissions => { })`. But if to use only behaviout subject - you should subscribe for it and also call refreshPermissions in other part of code.

Comment: deleted comments :) Question was why return type is not void :)

Comment: but if you subscribe to refreshPermissions then, you'll call the API twice.

Comment: This is okay, I was think to return behaviour subject, but in this case you will have only one events stream - `permissionsSubject`. With return the observable I can subscribe separately to events when permission has been loaded from server, and to permissions that has been set from any source, moreover in future I can add more methods `refreshPermissionsByServer2` and as each of them will return the observable I can separate events stream.